# passing parameter from view to library and return after process Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am going to built the custom library. I want to pass string from view to library and process and then return to same view after. My code looks like:

### application/libraries/MultiImageParser.php

```
 <?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    //return profile pic of img arrays.
      class MultiImageParser { 
          function parser($multiImage)   {    //get $prods->images here as parameter 
             $images = $multiImage;  //gets multiple image from controller like 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg
             $pieces = explode(",", $images); //explode make arrays.
             $one = $pieces[0];
             return $one;
          }
       }
```

### View

```
 <?php 
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $CI->load->library('multiImageParser');  //loading library from view
     $profilepic = $CI->multiImageParser->parser($prods->images);
     echo $profilepic;
 ?>
```

And I get this error `call to member function parser() on a non-object`. How can I resolve this.

Comment: You don't need to do `get_instance` in a view.
However, you shouldn't event do any library calls in the view but in the controller instead.

Comment: Its also possible to load library in view using get_instance. But is there any problem in loading library in view.

Comment: I agree with AdrienXL.. you should always try to do any of this type of work in your controller and refrain from doing anything in the view but to show content.

Comment: If its in controller then how can i pass variable from controller to library and then get return after process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are calling your library method. As per the **[CI Documentation - Creating Libraries](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)**:

> Object instances will always be lower case

```
$this->someclass->some_function();  // Object instances will always be lower case
```

So in your case it should be:

```
$profilepic = $this->multiimageparser->parser();
```

However, you should always do all this work in the Controller, not in the View to follow a correct MVC pattern

your controller should be like this:

```
 public function controller_method() {
    $this->load->library('MultiImageParser');
    $img = $this->multiimageparser->parser();
    $data = array(
        "profilepic" => $img
    );
    $this->load->view('view_name', $data);
}
```

and your View:

```
echo $profilepic;
```

Comment: I had not tried in controller. If its possible from view then it would require less code to written. So i thought it would be good. Does it has any bad impact to use library directly  from view.

Comment: It boils down on whether you want to have good code or not.. or what separates a good developer from a bad developer. With PHP and CI, you can do as much as you want wherever you want but should you?.. by following MVC structure and guidelines, you will have good readable code in the end rather than spaghetti code.

Comment: You're welcome Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: I think I can't do this with controller because there are many loops in which I have tp parse. I must do this from view. I can make simple helper for that. Any way thanks for your response.

Comment: if i were you I would run those loops in the controller including the results from your library, store them in an array, the pass that array to your view. Your controller does all the interaction with the library.. your view will just parse information

Answer (score 0):

You have got some string that is imploded array of image names glued by comma. Make your job of requested separation of that element (and consequently dedicating it to variable) in controller that loads your view. To explain myself bit better, this code should stay in the controller that is loading view file you posted here. Or in other words, in same controller where is generated `$prods->images` property. Also it doesn't need to be library, it can be (private/protected maybe?) method of same controller. But also, if you want it on different places used, you answered with helper option too.

Comment: Yes i need to use it in several places so i made a helper and its working like a charm now. I don't need to make a library for this simple function. Helper is okey.