# passing variable value from library to controller and then to view in CI 3.0

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, api, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to pass variable value from library function to controller and then view to get output.

For that my library code :

```
<?php                                                                                   

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * @description : Library to access MyOperator Public API
 */
Class My_Operator extends Admin_controller{

    protected $developers_url = 'https://developers.myoperator.co/';
    protected $token = 'XXXXXXXXX';

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function run() {
        # request for Logs
        $url = $this->developers_url . 'search';
        $fields = array("token" => $this->token);
        $result = $this->_post_api($fields, $url);

        $this->log("result");
        $this->log($result);
    }

    private function _post_api(Array $fields, $url) {
        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->log("url");
        $this->log($url);
        $this->log("fields");
        $this->log($fields);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result)
            return $result;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private function log($message) {
        print_r($message);
        echo "\n";
    }

}
```

extended `extends Admin_controller` from core file.

My Controller code is :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Myoperator extends Admin_controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('myoperator_model');
    }

    public function index()
   {
       try {
           $this->load->library('my_operator');  
           $data = $this->my_operator->run();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           var_dump($e->getMessage());
       }

       $this->load->view('admin/myoperator/view', $data);
   }
}
```

And my view code is :

```
<?php init_head(); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <?php
                echo $this->MY_Operator->run();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php init_tail(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I won't get desired output.
for this I refereed :

[codeigniter data passing controller->library->view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554394/codeigniter-data-passing-controller-library-view)

[Pass data from library to controller and then to view in CodeIgniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134312/pass-data-from-library-to-controller-and-then-to-view-in-codeigniter-2)

[passing parameter from view to library and return after process Code igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915676/passing-parameter-from-view-to-library-and-return-after-process-code-igniter)

When I'm running this code I got an error

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500

As per my understanding this `error` comes if there is any problem in server configuration, but the other pages from same application runs perfectly.

**edited :**
Previous error solved, some linking problem, but when I'm extended that class, gives new error:

> Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

is it possible to extend core file class into library class ?

Please help me to solve this problem. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try returning result from `run` function.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, Solved the problem, Some link problem. But got new error, Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php.

Comment: did you load session library any where?

Comment: actually I'm extending class that written in core file to library file, is it possible ?

Comment: sorry for late reply you can not extend core class like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem, just forgot to include `Admin_controller` file in `Myoperator` controller file.

here is my updated code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH. 'core/Admin_controller.php'; //forgot this line of code
class Myoperator extends Admin_controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('myoperator_model');
    }

    public function index()
   {
       try {
           $this->load->library('my_operator');  
           $data = $this->my_operator->run();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           var_dump($e->getMessage());
       }

       $this->load->view('admin/myoperator/view', $data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not extend `core` class of CI from library.But

> You can create entirely new libraries.
>
> You can extend native libraries.
>
> You can replace native libraries.

for more see [Codeigniter Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

to use core `CI files` in library.Create CI global instance using

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Then load required core files using `$CI`.

Comment: But if I removed that code `extends Admin_controller` it gives 500 error

Comment: And if put that code it give an error that : Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Comment: in view `print_r($data)` instead of calling library's function.What is output?

Comment: Thanks for help, problem solved, Forgot to include Admin_controller file in Controller file.

Comment: congrats glad to help.